# Copy worksheet from workbook and create a new workbook and save this file to new destination with name change

Tags: excel, vba, copy, save

I am trying to take one worksheet from a workbook, create a new workbook, and then save it to a new folder and name it December. This code runs through, but it opens a new workbook and doesn't save it to the destinated I have written down.

```vb
Sub Copysheetandsave()

    Set sourceWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("150")
    
    savePath = "C:\Users\"
    
    sourceWs.Copy
    Set newWb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    newWb.SaveAs Filename:=December
    
    newWb.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

```
Option Explicit '<<use this!

Sub Copysheetandsave()
    Dim sourceWs As WorkSheet, savePath As String

    Set sourceWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("150")

    savePath = "C:\Users\yourUserNameHere\" 'Save location

    sourceWs.Copy 
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs Filename:= savePath & "December.xlsx" 'use full path and extension
        .Close False 'no save needed
    End with

End Sub
```